# How to perfectly center grid-items while using CSS Grid auto-fit property?

Tags: html, css, centering, css-grid

I have this Grid:

[image: CSS Grid]

You can see the full code in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CarlosCordova/pen/gdmwOv)

The problem is that, due to `auto-fit` property, when changing screen size, some columns go down. I need that even if new rows appear, all the grid items should be centered in the grid container.

This is the scenario:

[image: Scenario]

```css
body {margin: 0}

.about-us__block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}

.about-us__container {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.about-us__text {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #35306B;
  color: #ebecec;
}

.about-us__text h6 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

.about-us__text p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
}

.about-us__item:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us__container">
  <div class="about-us__item">
    <div class="about-us__block"></div>
    <div class="about-us__text">
      <h6>John Doe</h6>
      <p>BlaBla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-us__item">
    <div class="about-us__block"></div>
    <div class="about-us__text">
      <h6>John Doe</h6>
      <p>BlaBla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-us__item">
    <div class="about-us__block"></div>
    <div class="about-us__text">
      <h6>John Doe</h6>
      <p>BlaBla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-us__item">
    <div class="about-us__block"></div>
    <div class="about-us__text">
      <h6>John Doe</h6>
      <p>BlaBla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying a lot of solutions, but none of them works.
I tried forcing the fourth grid-item to place in the 2nd column, but this occurs:
[image: .]

Comment: flex will do, grid not ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same layout on my project.

On the container try:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```